# Extract image link from XML with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, image

I have some JavaScript that should be getting this image URL[1] from an XML document with the following code. However Chrome's console returns `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null` on this line. Is the regex incorrect?

```
var image = $(post.description.match(/<br\/>(<a.*><img.*<\/a>)<br\/>/)[1]).addClass('photo');
```

[1] http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/391316_483838581645230_1080523933_s.jpg

The XML is structured like so:

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
Extendemos una cordial felicitación a Reserva de la Biosfera Banco Chinchorro que celebra su aniversario el día de hoy.
Un especial saludo a Maricarmen García, Directora de la Reserva y Líder 2010 del Programa de Liderazgo. ¡Estamos muy
orgullosos de su trabajo!<br /> <br /> We would like to co
]]>
<![CDATA[
ngratulate Banco Chinchorro Biosphere Reserve who is celebrating their anniversary today. A special greeting to Maricarmen
García, the Reserve&#039;s Director and 2010 MAR Leadership Fellow. We are so proud of your work!<br /> <br />
<a href="http://pyucatan.conanp.gob.mx/chincho.htm" target="_blank" rel="nofollow nofollow"
onmousedown="UntrustedLink.bootstrap($(this), &quot;HAQE2sh3f&quot;, event, bagof({}));">http://pyucatan.conanp.gob.mx/chincho.htm</a><br/><br/>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=483838581645230&amp;set=a.167790786583346.41662.123942950968130&amp;type=1&amp;relevant_count=1"
title="" target=""><img class="img" src="http://photos-c.ak.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ak-ash4/391316_483838581645230_1080523933_s.jpg" alt="" /></a>
]]>
</description>
```

Comment: Because the image URL is in the string inside the <description> node so I'd still need to parse through it.

Comment: @AlvinWong: Does one need to escape those in CDATA sections?

Comment: @Simpleton Can you point out what you are trying to match exactly? (extract the portion in your example that you are trying to extract...)

Comment: @AlvinWong: Why there? The >/< characters have no special meaning in regex (only to open lookbehind groups).

Comment: @AlvinWong Trying to match that img src pointed out in the questions marked [1]

Comment: So what actually is `post` and `post.description`? Simple string? XML object?

Comment: post is each iteration of an item in the RSS feed. Description is a child node that belongs to each post (item node).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the regex incorrect?

Yes. `/<br\/>(<a.*><img.*<\/a>)<br\/>/` tries to match br-tags without a space, and also in the string you gave us there is no `<br>` after the link. So, the match returns `null` and has no property "`1`".

Anyway, [Regex is not suited](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1048572) for this task. Just get the [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Node.textContent) of your `<description>` node, parse it as HTML with jQuery (see [Can jQuery Parse HTML Stored in a Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5951988/1048572)), or even as X[HT]ML with [`jQuery.parseXML`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/), and use a [selector to get](http://api.jquery.com/find/) the `a > img` element out of it, in order to read the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is a [big no-no](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not) for [parsing HTML/XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

You should try parsing with `jQuery.parseXML()`

Comment: The HTML does not need to be XML