# Getting relevant information from a GET response using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get

I'm trying to get only the necessary information from a GET request.  Here's the function I'm using:

```
this.updateTargetList = function(content) {
    $.get("index.php?AJAXmd=1", function (data) {
        var selector = "div.list";
        $(selector).html(data);
    });
}
```

The GET returns a whole bunch of html, more than I need, so it's loading that into the div whose class is "list".  For example, the get is returning:

```
<div class="a">.....
     <div class="b">.......
           <div class="list>........</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

How can I change data to only get the class or id that I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this. The easiest is to use the `load()` ajax shorthand method like so. replace `#selection` with the selector for the part of the DOM you would like to get.

```
$('div.list').load('index.php?AJAXmd=1 #selection');
```

You could also get the whole page using `$.get` or `$.ajax` and then create a jQuery object from the response and then select the information you want from it.

```
this.updateTargetList = function(content) {
    $.get("index.php?AJAXmd=1", function (data) {
        var selector = "div.list";
        var data = $(data);
        var selection = data.find('.list').html();
        $(selector).html(selection);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [Can jQuery Parse HTML Stored in a Variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5951988/can-jquery-parse-html-stored-in-a-variable)

```
$(myHtml).filter('#someid').doStuff();
```